# Links not working on Facebook Page Custom Tab

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-apps

I have created a custom tab for a Facebook page. Everything is displaying, the only issue happening is none of the link in that tab is working. Is there a special code that I need to add for Facebook Tab page in order to make the links work?

This is the facebook tab.

https://www.facebook.com/AstellasUS/app/2475799012460272/

And the links I have used basic HTML below

```
<li>Twitter: <a href="http://www.twitter.com/astellasus">twitter.com/astellasus</a></li>
<li>LinkedIn: <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/astellas-pharma">linkedin.com/company/astellas-pharma</a></li>
<li>YouTube: <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/AstellasUS">youtube.com/user/AstellasUS</a></li>
<li>Website: <a href="http://www.astellas.us">astellas.us</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are “not working”, because those sites forbid being displayed inside a frame on a different domain, via the `X-Frame-Options` header.

Trying to open those sites inside the app iframe doesn’t make that much sense to begin with - so simply add `target="_blank"` to those links, so that they open in a new window/tab.

Comment: Perfect also those links should be "https" and not "http" as per FB guidelines

Comment: For external links not necessarily, when you open them in a new window/tab, that is outside the “reach” of Facebook. But of course, if they are available in an HTTPS version, that should always be given preference these days ;-)